# How to add Name along with email and password to firebase database android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I add Name along with email and password to firebase database android?

I added an email and password with function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and call a function:

```
createNewUser(task.getResult().getUser());
```

when successfull and in createnewUser im doing this

```
private void createNewUser(FirebaseUser userFromRegistration) {
        String username = nameEditText.getText().toString();
        String email = userFromRegistration.getEmail();
        String userId = userFromRegistration.getUid();


        User user = new User();
        user.setName(username);
        user.setUid(userId);
        user.setEmail(email);



        Log.d("Raza",mDatabase.child("users").push().setValue(user).isSuccessful()+"");

    }
```

But I'm getting False at `Log.d` and the username is not added to my database.

My User Class is this:

```
public class User {


String name;
String uid;
String email;

public User(){
    // Default constructor required
}

public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
public void setUid(String uid){this.uid = uid;}
public void setEmail(String email){this.email = email;}

public String getName(){return this.name;}



}
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Try to comment the line with the log and add this line: `mDatabase.child("users").push().setValue(user);` Does it work?

Comment: @AlexMamo No its the same as Log.d...
it is not working thats why i applied log.d to check what's the status. and status im getting is false.

Comment: Please share the code for your mDatabase

Comment: My first guess is that you don't have permission to write to the database. Check the logcat output for a message on that.

Answer (score 0):

### Model Class

```
public class User {
public String uid;
public String email;
public String user_name;
 public User(){

}
public User(String uid, String email String user_name)
{
    this.uid = uid;
    this.email = email;
    this.user_name=user_name;
}
}
```

### and Push data into firebase data like that

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    User user = new User(firebaseUser.getUid(),
            firebaseUser.getEmail(),
            MySharedPreferences.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_NAME));
            database.child(Constants.ARG_USERS)
            .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
            .setValue(user)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
//  mOnUserDatabaseListener.onSuccess(context.getString(R.string.user_successfully_added));
                      } else {
//   mOnUserDatabaseListener.onFailure(context.getString(R.string.user_unable_to_add));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: cannot resolve MySharedPreferences
And its also converting Constants to SyncStateContract.Constants and Key_User_Name not found with Syncstate

Comment: cannot resolve MySharedPreferences
And its also converting Constants to SyncStateContract.Constants and Key_User_Name not found with Syncstate